# JFreeChart Bar chart Design Change

Tags: java, jfreechart, bar-chart

I am looking for a way to change the design of the Bar chart in JFreechart. Here is my excel graph. How can I change the jfreechart barchart in the below design format?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code can generate a similar chart. Does it suffice?

[image: bar chart example]

```
public class BarExample {
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException {
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataSet = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        dataSet.setValue(2, Integer.valueOf(1), Integer.valueOf(5));
        dataSet.setValue(7, Integer.valueOf(1), Integer.valueOf(10));
        dataSet.setValue(4, Integer.valueOf(1), Integer.valueOf(15));
        dataSet.setValue(9, Integer.valueOf(1), Integer.valueOf(20));
        dataSet.setValue(6, Integer.valueOf(1), Integer.valueOf(25));
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart
                ("Chart", "Number of Days", "Number of ECR", dataSet,
                        PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
        CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
        // Reduce margin between bars
        plot.getDomainAxis().setCategoryMargin(0.0);
        // Reduce left and right margin
        plot.getDomainAxis().setLowerMargin(0.0);
        plot.getDomainAxis().setUpperMargin(0.0);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                new File("chart.png"));
        ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(outputStream, chart, 1024, 768);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/). Consider making `setVisible()` _last_. Also, consider using the static factory method, `Integer.valueOf()`, instead of the constructor.